# Add small UI hint on why the "need answers" tab is empty

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav, filtering

For several days now, I wondered why the "**need answers**" tab for a tag I follow was empty. At first I thought this was a bug, but today I found out *it's not a bug, it's a feature*. It took me some time to spot (though now that I *know* what to look for it seems obvious :S):

[image: Tag on "need answers" tab]

The reason there's no questions here is because there's a "bounties" filter turned on at the moment (there are plenty of knockoutjs tagged questions needing answers). This is easy to miss, especially in my case: the filter was something I turned on several days ago, and that setting persisted, so when I came to the "need answers" tab a few days after I had forgotten all about that filter.

It's especially tricky, because that particular dropdown exists *only* on the "need answers" tab, not on the other two sibling tabs.

I'd suggest including a UX / UI hint that this particular filter is turned on, using the familiar *pop-out* effect of the culprit. For example:

[image: UI hint for bounty filter]

Another alternative that comes to mind is that the relevant dropdown goes back to default in new browser sessions.

And I guess there's plenty of other options too. But there's room for (a minor) improvement here.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying there's no results because the "bounties" filter is on. If so, I agree the UI is unclear.

Comment: @acbabis Yes. I've tried to clarify that in an edit.

Comment: "sort of" completed: in the current release invalid tags are marked as such

Answer (score 3):

The words "that filter combination" are an obvious shortcoming.  "Which filters are active again?"

It would be much more useful if it instead directly provided the information:

> Sorry, there are no results matching *bountied AND needs-answer AND [knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js)*

Even better, add the little <sup>(X)</sup> for removing filters.

---

This is not necessarily to the exclusion of including the "bountied" filter in other parts of the UI where filters are shown.

Answer (score -3):

Why not show the bounty filter being selected as a "tag" next to the normal ones, eg: [knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js) [has-a-bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/has-a-bounty)

Or if not using the same styling, put a textual indicator that only bountied questions are being shown next to the tag filter.

I added a mockup showing the Has-A-Bounty indicator on the same horizontal row as the tags; but under the bounty selector and with different styling for differentiation.

[image]

Comment: Something *like* this might work (hence neither down nor up vote from me), though visualizing something as a tag even though it *is not* a tag, may be confusing.

Comment: To be clear, I *do* like the fact that this answer actually *solves* an issue my own suggestion as well as the other answer doesn't solve: ***two* instead of *three* places on screen where active filters are shown** (three tabs top left, the tag, and the bounty filter => three tabs top left + the tag area).

Comment: I disagree with this as I think it'll make it look cluttered. I do like the suggestion, but I think it should be approached differently.

Comment: @Jeroen however, it could be formatted in a different way then a tag

Answer (score -4):

## Maybe it should look like this instead:

[image]

> [image]

Comment: **Like what?** I see you added a link, but it took me a while to find and it's pretty unreadable.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I see the difference...

Comment: In other words, add a link to reset the filters on the "need answers" tab.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, but making meta users figure it out let's them try the UX first-hand. :)

Comment: Needs more freehand circles.

Comment: If that's the case, then this UX failed :)

Comment: Yeah if it's a SMALL notice like that that people don't see right out... it's not a good UI tweak. I did not see the difference at first, and I had to look for the link to see it.... This UI is not exactly an improvement

Comment: It doesn't matter if you could figure out what change was made.  It matters if you could move from the state shown (with no answers) to the desired state (all answers).  If that link was available, with that text, and it reset the filters, it would be performing as I expected.

Comment: @AbMagil but if the link is available, with that text, but people don't see it because it's not really clear enough where it is or easily missable, have we REALLY improved on "unclear UI" here?

Comment: It's immediately below the main response ("That's a miss"), and while it's next to grey, understated text that could easily be missed, it's a link, which people naturally read when looking for a next step.

Comment: Links amidst subdued, grey, footerish text are going to be ignored.

Comment: @ABMagil I was actively looking for the change and did not see it. Very few people are going to read the small gray text under the big picture. They're just going to assume no results are there.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Done